# memory layout of c++ class member variables

Tags: c++

Basically I want to load member variables values from a data file, so my idea is to align data according to on RAM memory layout in file and then read it to memory from file directly.
For example for following class

```
class A {
 int a;
 int array_size;
 int *array;
};
```

In file, first 8 bytes I will write value of `a` and next 8 bytes to store `array_size` then for some next n bytes I will store `*array`.

While loading from will do something like this
Pseudo code

```
char buffer[1028]; //I will get 1028 from some kind of header it will be total memory size of class including array size;
read(fd,buffer,1028);
A *a = buffer; //Type cast to type class A
a->array = a + 16; //Set array base address.
```

Will my above approach work across different compiler and machine. (Don't worry about endiness). Will compiler guarantee some kind of alignment? I want file to be also interpreted by executable generated by different compiler and different machine.

Comment: Third line violates strict aliasing rule, just use `std::memcpy`. Who owns the memory at `a->array`? Do you expect the buffer to live as long as the array?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) will be an issue. As will padding between members (which is very compiler-specific).

Comment: @Quimby yes . That is just demo code. I will make sure buffer to live as long as array

Comment: I recommend not using this approach.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*` to hold the data.  Use a text-only file for the data file (at least for development purposes), and then later (if needed) figure out a binary format or use one of the many different serialization frameworks.

Comment: @BRUCE Then you might go one step further and do the deserialization properly using `std::memcpy` to fill in `A a;` object and again for filling, preferrably, `std::vector<int>` array.

Comment: @Quimby Whole point of doing all this is avoid copy for performance reason. I want to do this operation 1000s of time per sec

Comment: You need to create a standard layout class. This gives you that guarantee. See here for requirements: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class

Comment: The safest approach, don't make any assumptions on actual memory layout. Specify what the file layout is byte by byte and rebuild your C++ datastructures from that when loading. C++ has not been designed to be (binary) serializable out of the box. And "naive" approaches will run into problems with files that are shared between different machines/architectures and or programs compiled with different compile settings.

Comment: You can always get rid of your structure entirely and have accessor functions that fetch the data from the raw binary data loaded from disk, or even memory-mapped to disk. There's no reason why you need `int a` when you could have `int a() const` instead.

Comment: for this example, isn't it's easier to just set the 3 members directly?